# How do you say 'home is where the heart is' in traditional Chinese characters?

Tags: translation, characters

How do you say 'home is where the heart is' in traditional Chinese characters?
Is this correct?: 家是哪裡的心臟是

Comment: see iciba:（谚）心之所在即为家，金窝银窝，不如自家的狗窝；www provides translation to traditional characters

Comment: literally perhaps  无论心在哪里，家就在那里

Comment: An irrelevant comment: Chinese characters are to be _written_. You want to say something in Chinese, and write that down in traditional characters.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few different ways to do this.

Aurus Huang already suggested

> 心在哪裡，家就在哪裡。

above.

[Baidu](http://fanyi.baidu.com/?aldtype=85#en/zh/home%20is%20where%20the%20heart%20is) gives us:

> 心之所在即為家

This [Baidu Zhidao](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/139455691.html?qbl=relate_question_0&word=home%20is%20where%20the%20heart%20is) question also gives a lot of examples:

> 心中向往的地方就是你的家

> 家是心之所在

> 心所在的地方是家。

**but my absolute favorite, and honestly the best translation of this phrase has got to go to**:

> 心所向，家所在。

Answer (score 1):

心在哪裡，家就在哪裡。
This is a direct translation.

Comment: according to dictionaries and grammars: 哪里....哪里 (e.g.哪里有困难，他就出现在哪里), but 哪里。。。那里 also occurs: 哪里有困难，那里就有排忧解难的人民警察，哪里有灾难，那里就有浴血抗灾的人民警察

Comment: Use 哪裡. It's different from your example.

Comment: 这是无可争议的。所有的词典和语法书都同意第一答案。There is no argument, dictionaries and grammars all agree with answer #1.

Answer (score 1):

From a classical Chinese poem by 蘇軾:

“此心安處是吾鄉”